# Sentiment analysis in R (not using tm.plugin.tags)

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I'm using R version 3.0.2 and have installed the package `tm`. Previously, I also loaded a package called `tm.plugin.tags`. To get a measure of whether a text corpus was positive or negative I used the following approach:

```
library('tm')
library('tm.plugin.tags')

pos <- tm_tag_score(TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE)), tm_get_tags("Positiv"))
```

`tm.plugin.tags` seems to be no longer available for `R`. This was based on the following classification system http://www.wjh.harvard.edu/~inquirer/homecat.htm and I'm wondering if there is any other package or approach that I can use to achieve a similar result.

I have emailed the package maintainer of `tm` so I will post an update here once/if I receive a response.

Answer (score 3):

You can install tm.plugin.tags using the following command

```
install.packages("tm.plugin.tags", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at", type = "source")
```

This installs  without any problem

Thanks
Cheers