# Making a term document matrix from an excel file using R

Tags: r, csv, matrix, tm, term-document-matrix

For sentiment analysis using tm plugin webmining, I am to create a TermDocumentMatrix, as shown in the code sample below:
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/tm/docs/tm_tag_score

I have a csv file with headlines of articles on separate rows, in a total of 1 column and without a heading. My goal is to create a term document matrix (or PlainTextDocument, if possible) using the rows of headlines in my csv file, but so far I was only able to create a regular matrix:

```
#READ IN FILE
filevz <- read.csv("headlinesonly.csv")

#make matrix
headvzDTM <- as.matrix(filevz)

#look at dimension of file
dim(filevz)
#[1] 829   1

#contents of DTM
headvzDTM
       European.Central.Bank.President.Draghi.News.Conference..Text.                                        
  [1,] "Euro Gains Seen as ECB Bank Test Sparks Repatriation: Currencies"                                   
  [2,] "Euro-Area Inflation Rate Falls to Four-Year Low"                                                    
  [3,] "Euro-Area October Economic Confidence Rise Beats Forecast"                                          
  [4,] "Europe Breakup Forces Mount as Union Relevance Fades"                                               
  [5,] "Cyprus Tops Germany as Bailout Payer, Relatively Speaking"    
....//the entire contents are printed, I include the top 5 and last entry here

[829,] "Copper, Metals Plummet as Europe Credit-Rating Cuts Erode Demand Prospects"
```

I did not include a header in the csv file. This was the error message when I tried to begin the sentiment analysis:

```
pos <- tm_tag_score(TermDocumentMatrix(headvzDTM, 
                     control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE)), 
                     tm_get_tags("Positiv"))
```

Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'character')"

Is there a way to create a TermDocumentMatrix using the matrix I have created?

I had alternatively tried to create a reader to extract the contents of the csv file and place it into a corpus, but this gave me an error:

```
//read in csv
read.table("headlinesonly.csv", header=FALSE, sep = ";") 

//call the table by a name
headlinevz=read.table("headlinesonly.csv", header=FALSE, sep = ";") 

m <- list(Content = "contents")

ds <- DataframeSource(headlinevz)
elem <- getElem(stepNext(ds))

//make myreader
myReader <- readTabular(mapping = m)

//error message

> (headvz <- Corpus(DataframeSource(headlinevz, encoding = "UTF-8"),
+ readerControl = myReader(elem, language = "eng", id = "id1"
+ )))
```

Error in `[.default`(elem$content, , mapping[[n]]) : 
  incorrect number of dimensions

When I try other suggestions on this site (such as, [R text mining documents from CSV file (one row per doc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997364/r-text-mining-documents-from-csv-file-one-row-per-doc/17999144#17999144) ) , I continue having the problem of not being able to do sentiment analysis to an object of class "data.frame":

> hvz <- read.csv("headlinesonly.csv", header=FALSE)
>
> require(tm)
>
> corp <- Corpus(DataframeSource(hvz))
>
> dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
>
> pos <- tm_tag_score(TermDocumentMatrix(hvz, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE)), 
>   tm_get_tags("Positiv"))
>
> Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) : 
>    no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
>
> require("tm.plugin.tags")
>
> Loading required package: tm.plugin.tags
>
> sapply(hvz, tm_tag_score, tm_get_tags("Positiv"))
>
> Error in UseMethod("tm_tag_score", x) : 
>    no applicable method for 'tm_tag_score' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: And what happens when you try the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17999144/1036500 ?

Comment: I think it may be useful for you to look at how other people format their questions.  Your question could be improved a lot with code tags and a reproducible example.  Right now it's very difficult to read and parse out what is what.

Comment: Thank you, Ben and Tyler. I had seen the code in the link you posted before, and had run into a similar problem with it:

Comment: (I included the code and results at the end of my question for better readability)

Comment: I voted to close because no [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) was provided and the user never gave feedback so we can't diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to get `tm_tag_score` working, using a reproducible example that appears similar to your use-case.

First some example data...

```
examp1 <- "When discussing performance with colleagues, teaching, sending a bug report or searching for guidance on mailing lists and here on SO, a reproducible example is often asked and always helpful. What are your tips for creating an excellent example? How do you paste data structures from r in a text format? What other information should you include? Are there other tricks in addition to using dput(), dump() or structure()? When should you include library() or require() statements? Which reserved words should one avoid, in addition to c, df, data, etc? How does one make a great r reproducible example?"
examp2 <- "Sometimes the problem really isn't reproducible with a smaller piece of data, no matter how hard you try, and doesn't happen with synthetic data (although it's useful to show how you produced synthetic data sets that did not reproduce the problem, because it rules out some hypotheses). Posting the data to the web somewhere and providing a URL may be necessary. If the data can't be released to the public at large but could be shared at all, then you may be able to offer to e-mail it to interested parties (although this will cut down the number of people who will bother to work on it). I haven't actually seen this done, because people who can't release their data are sensitive about releasing it any form, but it would seem plausible that in some cases one could still post data if it were sufficiently anonymized/scrambled/corrupted slightly in some way. If you can't do either of these then you probably need to hire a consultant to solve your problem" 
examp3 <- "You are most likely to get good help with your R problem if you provide a reproducible example. A reproducible example allows someone else to recreate your problem by just copying and pasting R code. There are four things you need to include to make your example reproducible: required packages, data, code, and a description of your R environment. Packages should be loaded at the top of the script, so it's easy to see which ones the example needs. The easiest way to include data in an email is to use dput() to generate the R code to recreate it. For example, to recreate the mtcars dataset in R, I'd perform the following steps: Run dput(mtcars) in R Copy the output In my reproducible script, type mtcars <- then paste. Spend a little bit of time ensuring that your code is easy for others to read: make sure you've used spaces and your variable names are concise, but informative, use comments to indicate where your problem lies, do your best to remove everything that is not related to the problem. The shorter your code is, the easier it is to understand. Include the output of sessionInfo() as a comment. This summarises your R environment and makes it easy to check if you're using an out-of-date package. You can check you have actually made a reproducible example by starting up a fresh R session and pasting your script in. Before putting all of your code in an email, consider putting it on http://gist.github.com/. It will give your code nice syntax highlighting, and you don't have to worry about anything getting mangled by the email system."
examp4 <- "Do your homework before posting: If it is clear that you have done basic background research, you are far more likely to get an informative response. See also Further Resources further down this page. Do help.search(keyword) and apropos(keyword) with different keywords (type this at the R prompt). Do RSiteSearch(keyword) with different keywords (at the R prompt) to search R functions, contributed packages and R-Help postings. See ?RSiteSearch for further options and to restrict searches. Read the online help for relevant functions (type ?functionname, e.g., ?prod, at the R prompt) If something seems to have changed in R, look in the latest NEWS file on CRAN for information about it. Search the R-faq and the R-windows-faq if it might be relevant (http://cran.r-project.org/faqs.html) Read at least the relevant section in An Introduction to R If the function is from a package accompanying a book, e.g., the MASS package, consult the book before posting. The R Wiki has a section on finding functions and documentation"
examp5 <- "Before asking a technical question by e-mail, or in a newsgroup, or on a website chat board, do the following:  Try to find an answer by searching the archives of the forum you plan to post to. Try to find an answer by searching the Web. Try to find an answer by reading the manual. Try to find an answer by reading a FAQ. Try to find an answer by inspection or experimentation. Try to find an answer by asking a skilled friend. If you're a programmer, try to find an answer by reading the source code. When you ask your question, display the fact that you have done these things first; this will help establish that you're not being a lazy sponge and wasting people's time. Better yet, display what you have learned from doing these things. We like answering questions for people who have demonstrated they can learn from the answers. Use tactics like doing a Google search on the text of whatever error message you get (searching Google groups as well as Web pages). This might well take you straight to fix documentation or a mailing list thread answering your question. Even if it doesn't, saying “I googled on the following phrase but didn't get anything that looked promising” is a good thing to do in e-mail or news postings requesting help, if only because it records what searches won't help. It will also help to direct other people with similar problems to your thread by linking the search terms to what will hopefully be your problem and resolution thread. Take your time. Do not expect to be able to solve a complicated problem with a few seconds of Googling. Read and understand the FAQs, sit back, relax and give the problem some thought before approaching experts. Trust us, they will be able to tell from your questions how much reading and thinking you did, and will be more willing to help if you come prepared. Don't instantly fire your whole arsenal of questions just because your first search turned up no answers (or too many). Prepare your question. Think it through. Hasty-sounding questions get hasty answers, or none at all. The more you do to demonstrate that having put thought and effort into solving your problem before seeking help, the more likely you are to actually get help. Beware of asking the wrong question. If you ask one that is based on faulty assumptions, J. Random Hacker is quite likely to reply with a uselessly literal answer while thinking Stupid question..., and hoping the experience of getting what you asked for rather than what you needed will teach you a lesson."
```

Put example data in a data frame...

```
df <- data.frame(txt = sapply(1:5, function(i) eval(parse(text=paste0("examp",i))))
)
```

Now load the packages `tm` and `tm.plugin.tags` (hat tip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19331289/1036500)

```
require(tm)
install.packages("tm.plugin.tags", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at", type = "source")
require(tm.plugin.tags)
```

Now transform data frame of text to a corpus

```
corp <- Corpus(DataframeSource(df))
```

Now compute tag score. Note that the tag score function includes a `TermDocumentMatrix` function, which operates on the **corpus** object, *not* the document term matrix as you were attempting.

```
pos <- tm_tag_score(TermDocumentMatrix(corp, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE)), tm_get_tags("Positiv"))

sapply(corp, tm_tag_score, tm_get_tags("Positiv"))
```

And here's the output, same for `pos` as the `sapply` function, in this case:

```
 1  2  3  4  5 
 4  6 16 10 29
```

Does that answer your question?