# package ‘tm.plugin.tags’ alternative for R version 3.0.2

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

Does anyone know of an alternative for the package ‘tm.plugin.tags’ for R version 3.0.2?

I searched a bit on StackOverflow and found this post ([Sentiment analysis in R (not using tm.plugin.tags)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253824/sentiment-analysis-in-r-not-using-tm-plugin-tags)) relating to the topic in which the only solution given was to use this code to install it:

```
install.packages("tm.plugin.tags", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at", type = "source")
```

However, it does not work for me:

```
install.packages("tm.plugin.tags", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at", type = "source")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tm.plugin.tags’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

I also tried the same approach to installing tm.plugin.sentiment (which is what I am actually after), but it also did not work:

```
install.packages("tm.plugin.sentiment", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at", type = "source")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tm.plugin.sentiment’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this : `install.packages("tm.plugin.sentiment", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org",dependencies=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not work. I got the following: Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0

   package ‘tm.plugin.sentiment’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tm.plugin.sentiment’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

Comment: Whta is your `sessionInfo()`? which OS?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the latest tm libray required a R version number to greater than 3.1.0

```
Version:    0.6
Depends:    R (≥ 3.1.0), NLP (≥ 0.1-2)
Imports:    parallel, slam (≥ 0.1-31), stats, tools, utils
```

But the R version in ubuntu repository is only 3.0.2.

You can follow the link [install r 3.1.1 on ubuntu 14.04](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/07/install-r-base-3-1-1-ubuntu-14-04/) to install the latest r-base 
and r-core package. And then you can install all package related with tm library.